# Binding a custom control in a pivot item to the current item in the pivot control's ItemsSource

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I have a pivot control which is bound to a list through the ItemsSource attribute.

In the ItemTemplate I would like to place a custom control, in which I would like to bind controls to the current item in the pivot's list.

I'm looking for something around

```
<MyControl Item="{Binding <Something here>}" />
```

But am not sure what <something here> should be to point to the current item in the control's databound list?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but if this control is going inside the PivotItem then isn't the path you are looking for just:

```
<MyControl Item="{Binding}" />
```

e.g. if using a TextBlock then you might use:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
```

- and this would then use the ToString() of the current pivot item

Or if using a complicated user control you might use:

```
<MySpecialControl DataContext="{Binding}" />
```

Sorry if I've got this wrong!

Comment: Thanks Stuart, that's seemed like what I was looking for, but on trying that I get a parsing error? (leaving my control without the binding runs ok)

Comment: What is `Item`? Do you mean `DataContext`?

Comment: Thanks Stuart, you didn't miss anything - I did! - the DataContext is what I needed. I tried to add a property to my custom control, then set it to {Binding} in the parent and use the setter to set the DataContext, which of course is silly now that I know I can simply use the DataContext attribute to begin with!

Answer (score 1):

You could do one of two things (that immediately spring to mind):

1. Include the information you need in the object that your list item binds to. This is likely to be repetitive and probably difficult to manage, but I don't know the details of your data, so it's hard to say.
2. Use a proxy for the `Pivot.SelectedItem` property, which you add as a resource to the page and bind to the pivot's `SelectedItem` property. You can then reference that resource as you would any other resource to get at the selected item.

If you're not familiar with this proxy concept, then [Dan Wahlin's post on the subject](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2009/08/20/creating-a-silverlight-datacontext-proxy-to-simplify-data-binding-in-nested-controls.aspx) should help.